# Clockwork - Scaling dynos... failed ! No such process type clock defined in Procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, clockwork

I'm using `clockwork` for the first time. I followed the Heroku guide, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-ruby, but when I run `heroku ps:scale clock=1`, I get this error:

> Scaling web dynos... failed
>    !    No such process type web defined in Procfile.

My `Procfile` looks like this:

> web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
>
> worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
>
> clock: bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb

The project had already been pushed to Heroku with the `web` and `worker` processes, and it worked fine.

I did `foreman check` and it says:
`valid procfile detected (web, worker, clock)`

I also did `heroku run bash` and the Procfile is there.

Any ideas what I may have missed?

Comment: My bad, I pushed to Heroku, but I was not on the master branch. I pushed to master and then ran `heroku ps:scale clock=1` and it worked.